# Getting rid of alerts for responses

Tags: support, alerts

The top-of-the-page alerts are useful for knowing about badges and such. But the StackExchange "global mail" system already notifies you of comments or answers. So I really want to stop the top-of-page alerts from showing up just for a comment.

This seems to be a new feature, added today; is there a way to shut it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That feature was already there.

That happens when you got a comment on an answer or a question X number of hours ago since you have last been on, so it notifies you twice.

That seems to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Answer (score 2):

The thing that's odd to me is that sometimes comment notifications end up in my inbox, and sometimes they end up in an alert.

I think it would be much better if almost everything is shuttled into the inbox except for only a few instances, such as mod messages.